# Is there a way to define a pair of tuple as argument of a function ? I'm stucked with this "tuple parameter unpacking is not supported in Python 3"

Tags: parameters, tuples, python-3.6

My code is supposed to return the euclidean distance based on these 2 tuples:

```
def distance_points((x1, y1), (x2, y2)):
    dist = ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)** 0.5
    return dist
print(distance_points((1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 1.0)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your function and do tuple unpacking in function body ([as stated in official *PEP 3113 -- Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/#no-loss-of-abilities-if-removed)). For example:

```py
def distance_points(p1, p2):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = p1, p2
    dist = ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5
    return dist


print(distance_points((1.0, 1.0), (2.0, 1.0)))
```

Comment: Thanks ! It solved the issue! :)